# PostgreSQL fast search with jsonb field

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with a `jsonb` field. An one-dimensional array is stored here, in fact - a list of some IDs, like this:

```
[254622, 301359, 309207, 334299, 351963, 355482, 350938]
```

Also this field have an index:

```
CREATE INDEX users_log_actions_idx ON public.users_list_orders 
USING gin (users_log_actions);
```

In my query I do a search by this field (simplified version, without wome WHERE's conditions):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    users_list_orders
WHERE
    users_list_orders.user_id != '239118'
AND 
    NOT ( users_log_actions @> '239118' )
```

The problem is: my app performs hundreds of similar queries per second (of course, with different user IDs), sometimes this query is very fast (in about 0.2 seconds), and sometimes very slow (>15 seconds). I found out that the bottleneck is a search by jsonb field (users_log_actions), so I'd be grateful for any recommendations on how to speed up this.

**UPDATE:**

EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers, format text) on this query:

```
Limit  (cost=1.36..53.32 rows=1 width=313) (actual time=0.470..0.473 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=25
  InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
    ->  Result  (cost=0.50..0.51 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.100..0.101 rows=1 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=5
          InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
            ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..0.50 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.097..0.098 rows=1 loops=1)
                  Buffers: shared hit=5
                  ->  Index Only Scan Backward using users_list_orders_pkey on users_list_orders users_list_orders_1  (cost=0.42..39525.78 rows=503412 width=4) (actual time=0.096..0.097 rows=1 loops=1)
                        Index Cond: (id IS NOT NULL)
                        Heap Fetches: 1
                        Buffers: shared hit=5
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..102524.47 rows=1973 width=313) (actual time=0.469..0.470 rows=1 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=25
        ->  Index Scan using public_users_list_orders_order_category_id2_idx on users_list_orders  (cost=0.42..75900.87 rows=15889 width=312) (actual time=0.426..0.426 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (order_category_id = '18'::smallint)
              Filter: ((user_id <> 239118) AND (order_reported <= '50'::smallint) AND (NOT (users_log_actions @> '239118'::jsonb)) AND (NOT (users_log_hidden @> '239118'::jsonb)) AND (order_active = 1) AND ((order_daily_limit = 0) OR (order_daily_counter < order_daily_limit)) AND ((order_overall_limit = 0) OR (order_overall_counter < order_overall_limit)) AND ((id)::double precision >= round((random() * ($1)::double precision))))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 4
              Buffers: shared hit=21
        ->  Index Scan using users_main_pkey on users_main  (cost=0.42..1.67 rows=1 width=9) (actual time=0.041..0.041 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (id = users_list_orders.user_id)
              Filter: ((user_balance_usd > 0.05) AND (users_list_orders.order_price_usd < user_balance_usd))
              Buffers: shared hit=4
Planning time: 2.209 ms
Execution time: 0.559 ms
```

Comment: Can you please post an EXPLAIN plan of your query? That will help us understand how postgres is executing it.

Comment: The plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** for a slow execution would be more helpful

Comment: That execution plan cannot stem from the query in your question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've updated my execution plan in my question with explain (analyze, buffers, format text).